# How to install debugger in my NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to install debugger in my NetBeans 6.9.1.

I am using web applications which are communicating to each other and I am also using *RVM* with 2 different gemset which are having same version of Ruby and Rails install separately.

So how can I install debugger

I tried with this but not able to install this gem

```
 ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
 ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)
 linecache19 (0.5.12)
```

Getting this error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
samarth:~/project/MyECF-Pacer-Service$ gem install ruby-debug-base19
/home/samarth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable     dir /home/samarth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@persi/bin in PATH, mode 042777
WARNING:  Error fetching data: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)         (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'ruby-debug-base19' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: ruby-debug-base19
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it by downloading the following versions manually, changing directory to the download location and run gem install on the following versions:

linecache19-0.5.13.gem
ruby-debug-base19.0.11.26.gem

You can fetch them from: http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-debug19/